# Infinite Loop Drawing in OpenGL and Broken Lines issue

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, glut, infinite-loop

#### Infinite Loop Question

I want to achieve the effect as shown the picture:

[image]

I am generating this by including an infinite loop inside the `glutDisplayFunct` callback function, and which is not good as i cannot then process any input from the keyboard. The other method of which i can think is to probably use the glut's explicit window refresh functions.

I want to know how can i insert an infinite loop and also check for keyboard input. Here is the sample code i have made. It simply implements the DDA algorithm and attempts to draw infinite lines by generating random coordinates and colours.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

int width;
int height;

void dda (int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
  int del_x, del_y, sample_steps, i = 1;
  double x_incr, y_incr, x, y;

  del_x = x2 - x1;
  del_y = y2 - y1;
  sample_steps = (abs (del_x) > abs (del_y)) ? abs (del_x) : abs (del_y);

  x_incr = del_x / (double) sample_steps;
  y_incr = del_y / (double) sample_steps;

  x = x1;
  y = y1;


  glBegin (GL_POINTS);
  while (i<=sample_steps)
  {
    glVertex2f ((2.0 * x)/width, (2.0 * y)/height);
    x += x_incr;
    y += y_incr;
    i++;
  }
  glEnd ();

  glFlush ();
}

void keypress_handler (unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
  if (key == 'q' || key == 'Q')
  {
    glutLeaveMainLoop ();
  }
}

void init_screen (void)
{
  glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
  glClearColor (0, 0, 0, 1);
  glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glLoadIdentity ();
  glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void test_dda (void)
{
  int x1, y1, x2, y2;
  float r, g, b;

  int i=1;

  glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  srand (time(NULL));
  width = glutGet (GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
  height = glutGet (GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);

  while (i)
  {
    x1 = rand () % width  - (width  /2);  /* Global */
    y1 = rand () % height - (height /2); /* Global */
    x2 = rand () % width  - (width  /2);  /* Global */
    y2 = rand () % height - (height /2); /* Global */

    r = rand () / (float) RAND_MAX;
    g = rand () / (float) RAND_MAX;
    b = rand () / (float) RAND_MAX;

    glColor3f (r, g, b);
    dda (x1, y1, x2, y2);
    printf ("\r%d", i);
    i++;
  }

}

void reshape (int w, int h)
{
  glViewport (0, 0, w, h);
  glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity ();
  gluOrtho2D (-1, 1, -1, 1);
  glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  glutInit (&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
  init_screen ();
  glutCreateWindow ("DDA");
  glutDisplayFunc (test_dda);
  glutReshapeFunc (reshape);
  glutKeyboardFunc (keypress_handler);

  glutMainLoop ();

  printf ("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

#### Broken lines when first drawn

Also i have an additional question, which is like this:

When i uncomment the infinite loop (the `while (i)`) inside the `test_dda` function and run the executable with 1280x960 screen size every line drawn shows as broken lines, they seems look something like dashed lines. But, if i do not infinitely loop in this function and draw the lines with some other way, like forcing OpenGL to redraw, the lines shows as they should be displayed. I have noticed that when drawing the first time, the lines show broken. The broke lines of which i am talking is shown below:

[image]

To understand what i am saying do the following to get the effect. Change the `while (i)` to `while (i<1000)` . This will draw 1000 lines on the screen. When i run with this change with 1280x960 window size, the window is drawn 2 times. The first time the lines are drawn shows as broken as the above image. The moment 1000 lines are drawn, the window is cleared again the it is drawn again, but this time the lines shows as they should be. Why this is happening.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to. The infinite loop already happens inside `glutMainLoop()`. It will call your display function over and over again till the program is closed. To keep the output of previous frames (i.e. drawing over them), don't clear the color buffer with `glClear()`.

As for the broken lines: Don't draw lines pixel by pixel. While I didn't have a closer look, you most likely have some discrepancy caused by your view/projection matrix (i.e. you're drawing the dots with too much spacing). Instead, use OpenGL calls to draw lines.

What you're trying to do here is essentially trying to do software rendering on top of hardware accelerated rendering, which is just weird and not really recommended.

Comment: The main goal of the code was to manually implement the line drawing algorithm and not use internal routines. The algorithm i am using is the very basic one (DDA), and which runs fine. The pixels are not drawn with too much spacing, for the lines with dely/delx < 1, sampling on X direction and get Y, and for > 1 does vice versa. So the lines being drawn is continuous, and would not have any gaps.

Comment: On the other hand, the display function is not being drawn over and over, for example, when i minimize the window it is being redrawn, or when i resize the window it is being redrawn, and which is very slow, drawing (unlike what it would have in the `while (1)` loop.

Comment: You have to force the redraw, e.g. just call `glutPostRedisplay()` once you're done with rendering to redraw next iteration/frame. Also, I know the algorithm you used, but I guess the gaps are still caused due to this approach not being meant to be used here (e.g. it would be better suited for direct pixel manipulation). The gaps might be caused due to rounding (did you try `glSmooth()`?).

Comment: but the thing is that when i print the pixel values (in number) they show as adjacent plots. Also only the first time draw shows the broken lines, and the subsequent redraws shows the line correctly. This is main thing i am asking.

Comment: Not sure, but I'd guess some state/matrix being off. E.g. you don't call reshape before drawing to set up the projection matrix the same way (unless that's done by GLUT upon first opening the window; no experience here).

Answer (score 1):

The "display" function (`test_dda` in your case) is called every time the window needs to be redrawn. The event handling code in GLUT get no change of running if you are in an infinite loop inside the display function.

Instead use a timer, and draw one line in the timer function and then call a function to force GLUT to redraw the window, where you "flush" the GL pipe.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the starting solution you are adopting is conceptually wrong.

Don't take me bad :)

If the point is to draw constantly lines over and over, one possible solution would be to segment the process in this way:

- FRAME 1 STEP1: You draw the lines on a framebuffer mapped to a texture over a quad containing the working texture
- FRAME 1 STEP2: You draw a quad with the working texture
- GLUT INPUT CALLBACK
- FRAME 2 STEP1: You draw the lines on a framebuffer mapped to a texture over a quad containing the working texture
- FRAME 1 STEP2: You draw a quad with the output working texture
- GLUT INPUT CALLBACK

And so on.....

Comment: definitely it is not the way to be done, i am new to glut and opengl, therefore need to get into the thing. At this moment it is a bit complicated to understand the way you suggested, but i will read about these and try it.